# Android - How to create own handler of android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT

Tags: android, picker

My `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <activity android:name=".PickerActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_DOCUMENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:priority="999">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE"/>
            <data android:mimeType="*/*"/>
            <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I'm trying to create my own picker for action `android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT`, but nothing works. On old Androids like 4.4.2 everything works perfect, but on Android 7 code

```
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT).setType("image/*"), 0);
```

ALWAYS starts by default Android stock application `com.android.documentsui/.DocumentsActivity`. Is that a "feature" of new Android, and I can't now handle this action? Or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do your other intent filters work?

Comment: @greenapps, yes